# XML Outputter adds extra non ascii character

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am using following XML outputter for writing xml files on basis of CSV data.

```
public override void Output(IRow input, IUnstructuredWriter output)
    {
        IColumn badColumn = input.Schema.FirstOrDefault(col => col.Type != typeof(string));
        if (badColumn != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Column '{0}' must be of type 'string', not '{1}'", badColumn.Name, badColumn.Type.Name));
        }

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output.BaseStream, this.fragmentSettings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(this.rowPath);
            foreach (IColumn col in input.Schema)
            {
                var value = input.Get<string>(col.Name);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    // Skip null values in order to distinguish them from empty strings
                    writer.WriteElementString(this.columnPaths[col.Name] ?? col.Name, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It works really fine and jobs finishes completely without any errors however, on preview and downloading the file there is another extra character which causes in failure of that xml file being read. I have tried with fragment level and Auto as conformance levels.

My sample output obtained is

[image]

and the extra character between the 2 tags is causing problem while reading the file.

Comment: did you peek at the value while writing it out (on your last line of code there) to rule out that the data has this character to begin with? I might also suspect encoding changed in your process, but you would normally see that at the beginning or for certain characters.

Comment: As i run the job with ADLA, it might not be possible to peek and check for character comparisons. Do you know of any method with which i can get more details about error?
PS. very new to Azure data lake

Comment: you can't put a breakpoint on the last line of code? maybe you need something like this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/11/04/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: For now it can't be accomplished. Azure data lake is in preview and the best i could get is the execution graph which outputs only error name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by explicitly providing the encoding settings as well as closing tags with the code below

```
private XmlWriterSettings fragmentSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    };

 public override void Output(IRow input, IUnstructuredWriter output)
    {
        IColumn badColumn = input.Schema.FirstOrDefault(col => col.Type != typeof(string));
        if (badColumn != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Column '{0}' must be of type 'string', not '{1}'", badColumn.Name, badColumn.Type.Name));
        }
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output.BaseStream, this.fragmentSettings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(this.rowPath);
            foreach (IColumn col in input.Schema)
            {
                var value = input.Get<string>(col.Name);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    // Skip null values in order to distinguish them from empty strings
                    writer.WriteElementString(this.columnPaths[col.Name] ?? col.Name, value);
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement(); //explicit closing tag for stream
        }
    }
```

This outputs a well formed XML which can be easily read with any xml reader.

Comment: ahh nice, so it was encoding. it threw me off because the problem was in the middle.

Comment: Did you take a look at the example outputter on the GitHub site (https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats)?

Comment: Yes, I did the modifications with example outputter. The current git implementation is buggy with closing tags and encoding if files are on scale of GBs.